# Python regex - find words before a pattern match

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

```
text1="Information for Conformity of Production for OVC-HEV \n  \nCombined \nCO2 emission (g/km) MC02,CS,COP \n216.66 \nAFCO2,CS \n1.02 \n \n \n2.1.2.2.2. CO2 mass emission of OVC-HEVs in case of a charge-depleting Type 1 test \n"
```

I would like to get to words before the pattern `(\n2.1.2.2.2.)` using regex.

Expected output :

```
Combined CO2 emission (g/km) MC02,CS,COP 216.66 AFCO2,CS 1.02
```

I wrote a regex string that searches words after 2.1.2.2.2
but not sure on the backward search.

This is what i tried..

```py
text1='\n \n \n \nInformation for Conformity of Production for OVC-HEV \n  \nCombined \nCO2 emission (g/km) MC02,CS,COP \n216.66 \nAFCO2,CS \n1.02 \n \n \n2.1.2.2.2. CO2 mass emission of OVC-HEVs in case of a charge-depleting Type 1 test \n \nTest 1 \n \nCO2 Mass Emission (g/km) \nCombined \nCalculated Value MCO2,CD \n17.27 \n'

m8A = re.search(r'\b(2.1.2.2.2. CO2 mass emission of OVC-HEVs).*((?:\n.*){7})', text1)

d8A = {}

if m8A:

    d8A[m8A.group(1).strip()] = m8A.group(2).replace('\n', '').strip()

print(d8A)
```

Comment: Could you please share the regex you tried to match what you need?

Comment: So you want to split the string into 3 parts on blank lines and then join the middle part to a single line?

Comment: Or, get all lines from the paragraph above `2.1.2.2.2.` that all start with word chars. We need exact requirements to avoid guesswork.

Comment: i would like to get 7 characters before the pattern 2.1.2.2.2. i have edited the question with what i have tried

Comment: Yes, but `r'\b(2.1.2.2.2. CO2 mass emission of OVC-HEVs).*((?:\n.*){7})'` is clearly not getting what is *above* the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using

```py
(?m)^(\S.*(?:\n\S.*)*)(?:\n[ \t]*){2,}2\.1\.2\.2\.2\.
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kKYysL/2). *Details*:

- `(?m)` - multiline modde on
- `^` - start of a line
- `(\S.*(?:\n\S.*)*)` - Group 1: a non-whitespace char and then zero or more chars other than line break chars (as many as possible), and then zero or more occurrences of a newline + a non-whitespace chars + the rest of the line
- `(?:\n[ \t]*){2,}` - two or more consecutive sequences of: a newline, zero or more spaces or tabs
- `2\.1\.2\.2\.2\.` - a `2.1.2.2.2.` string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/jnFvUx):

```py
import re
text1="Information for Conformity of Production for OVC-HEV \n  \nCombined \nCO2 emission (g/km) MC02,CS,COP \n216.66 \nAFCO2,CS \n1.02 \n \n \n2.1.2.2.2. CO2 mass emission of OVC-HEVs in case of a charge-depleting Type 1 test \n"
rx = r"(?m)^(\S.*(?:\n\S.*)*)(?:\n[ \t]*){2,}2\.1\.2\.2\.2\."
m = re.search(rx, text1)
if m:
    print( m.group(1).strip() )
```

Output:

```
Combined 
CO2 emission (g/km) MC02,CS,COP 
216.66 
AFCO2,CS 
1.02
```